# Unable to connect mysql database using mysql1 package on flutter web For Flutter Automation

Tags: flutter, webautomation

I'm tying to connect to my `mySql` database using `mySql1` package. Here's my code of **DB Connection**.

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Database {

  static var s = ConnectionSettings(
    user: "User",
    password: "Password",
    host: "host",
    port: 3306,
    db: "db",
  );

static Future<MySqlConnection> connect() async{
  return await MySqlConnection.connect(s);

}}
```

**Expected Results:** It should connect the DB with my Flutter Code for Web.

**Actual Results:** Unable to connect the DB

Comment: does your Flutter web application has the necessary permissions to access the MySQL database.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @joy No Necessary Permission is there. Just need to use plugin mysql1

Answer (score 0):

The mysql1 plugin is not compatible with the web. A safety issue, no doubt.